# good tutorial for adding solr search to my website in eclipse

Tags: solr

I'm looking for good tutorials for adding solr search to my existing website. Any tutorial / guide providing step by step details  for adding solr to my website in ECLIPSE for the same would be helpful.

When the user enters a text in the search box and presses the enter button, solr search should work in the backend and fetch results. So is there any tutorial/ demo websites available developed in eclipse ? Kindly help.

thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Try [**ajax solr**](https://github.com/evolvingweb/ajax-solr).it is very easy to use and fast also